# Movie about an alien boy who has black dots on his face for wishes

Tags: story-identification, movie

I once watched this movie on TV in 2009 or 2010.

It's about a quiet kid who has a father works at his school. He also has an alien foster brother from space, who has blue suit, red hair and black dots - each dots represent a wish. There's a scene where the father and the mother quarrel about the wishes, and the father wishes the fridge door would close and open on its own so the dots all disappeared from the foster son's face.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It must be [*Das Sams*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0265691/) (2001), a German story.

I have never seen it personally, but it is about a man (Mr. Taschenbier) who meets this strange hobbit size creature. The "boy" has red hair, blue clothes and has blue dots on his face which grant wishes. With every wish a dot disappears.

[image: Das Sams]

Comment: OMG thank you so much! I've been searching for the movie for a long time!

Comment: Lol. I knew the book but didn't know it was a movie!

Comment: [Am Sonntag scheint die Sonne, Am Montag kommt Herr Mohn
Am Dienstag hab ich Dienst, Das wisst ihr sicher schon, Am Mittwoch war mitte der woche das ist klar, Am Donnerstag da donnert es, Das fand ich wunderbar
Am Freitag hab ich frei gehabt, 
doch was passierte dann, 
Am Samstag kam das Sams zu mir damit fing alles an.](https://www.lyrix.at/t/das-sams-sonntag-samstag-c54)

Comment: @Valorum: The book was first in this case (published in the 1970s), I know it from my childhood. The movie came only much later in the 2000s.

Comment: @Valorum  Apparently there were three films, with the sequels being `Sams in Gefahr` and `Sams im Gluck`.  I haven't been able to find any confirmation of a US release, but the English title for the film is `The Slurb`

Comment: In total there are 11 books. "Sams" comes from the german "Samstag" (means Saturday), so logical the English one should be named "Satur"... After helping Mr Taschenbier (Pocketbeer...) his family members take turns in caring for the Sams. His son, an uncle and other have good or bad plans with this awesome creature...